# Propagate ListBoxItem IsSelected trigger to child control

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, listbox, custom-controls

I'm developing a CheckedListBox with self removable `ListBoxItem`s. The problem is that an item only gets checked if the user clicks on the `CheckBox` area, which is kind of awkward.

How do I create `ListBoxItem` triggers (`IsSelected`) to check the checkboxes on a "DataSourced" `ListBox`? Eg:

[image]

Below is my control (all other code have been omitted for brevity):

```
<ListBox x:Name="executors" ItemsSource="{Binding Executors}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="121" Margin="23,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="362">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <CheckBox Margin="4,8" IsChecked="{Binding Enabled}">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Description}">

                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </CheckBox>
                            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveExecutorCommand, ElementName=executors}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Background="White" Height="22" Width="22" Grid.Column="1">
                                <Image Source="trash.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="14" Height="14" />
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Executors is a `ObservableCollection` of `Executor` which has `Enabled` and `Description` as members.

Comment: @mm8 mind to tell us why did you -1 this?

Answer (score 0):

For further reference for those who come across this same question, here's a working snippet I have done. I couldn't find any working sample anywhere, so this might be of much use.

The main idea here was to either propagate the selection event to the `CheckBox`es, which sounds too much of a work, or to simple extend the `CheckBox` selection area to fit the `ListBoxItem`.

Below is a sample on how to achieve the second option:

```
<ListBox x:Name="executors" ItemsSource="{Binding Executors}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="121" Margin="23,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="362" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Description}" IsChecked="{Binding Enabled}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0"/>
                            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveExecutorCommand, ElementName=executors}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Width="21" Height="21" Background="White" Grid.Column="1">
                                <Image Source="trash.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="14" Height="14" />
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

This should produce the following:

[image]